# What is the stressed syllable in perseverance?

Tags: pronunciation

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perseverance

> perseverance
>
> UK  /ˌpɜː.sɪˈvɪə.rəns/ US  /ˌpɝː.səˈvɪr.əns/

Why is the stress on vɪr not on sə?

Comment: I don't understand a "why" question about regional practices. Yes, it's pronounced differently in UK vs US; *why* is there a difference? Well, just because?

Answer (score 1):

*Perseverance* shares an etymology with the word 'severe' (grave, serious) which has the same emphasis in its pronunciation.

I suspect you might be assuming it should be pronounced with the same emphasis as in the word 'severance', but this comes from the word 'sever' (to separate), which is a different word entirely with a different etymology.

'Severe' comes directly from the Latin *severus*, whereas 'sever' comes indirectly from the Latin *separare*.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was thinking about preserve

Comment: @Tim *Preserve* is an entirely unrelated word, from Latin *servare*. It also has a different prefix - the Latin *pre-* meaning 'before.